# left Join to openquery

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to make a view through a join of different tables and an OPENQUERY and then filter with the WHERE by one of the columns that returns the view. When I do not put anything in the where it returns results but when I try to filter it, I get an error:

> OLE DB provider "ORAOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "SRV_BASEDEDATOSX" returned message "ORA-01403: No se ha encontrado ningún dato".
>   Mens. 7330, Nivel 16, Estado 2, Línea 1
>   Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "ORAOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "SRV_BASEDEDATOSX".

The SQL statement that I use is this:

```
SELECT P.idp, P.cod, R.name, P.idtp, T_P.tp, I.i, P_I.txt
FROM OPENQUERY(SRV_BASEDEDATOSX, 'SELECT rcod, name FROM recetas') AS R
RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.DISH AS P ON P.cod = R.rcod
INNER JOIN dbo.DISH_I AS P_I ON P_I.idp = P.idp
INNER JOIN dbo.TYPE_P AS T_P ON T_P.idtp = T_P.idtp
INNER JOIN dbo.LENGUAJE AS I ON I.idI = P_I.idi
```

I work on SQL SERVER 2014. I have done different tests and I think the error could be in the comparison of `ON R.rcod = P.cod`. I use a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` so that I can get rid of the results of the second table even if the condition is not met.

When I make a query about this, it returns all the elements except the `ON R.rcod = P.cod` condition is true. What I need is for you to return all the records to me always.

Please help me with my SQL statement since I can not find a solution. Thank you very much to all.

Comment: may be you need type casting. try cast(R.rcod as int)= P.cod --write the type of P.cod instead of int

Comment: Thank you very much doing the cast () has helped me so that now if all the results come out but I thought that the second part of the problem would also be solved.

This sql statement is a view and now I want to do a where for a column of the view: `WHERE TXT LIKE '%caballa%'`

But this one brings me back to the previous error. I know that there is a minimum register that meets the filter.

Comment: have a try with changing INNER JOIN s to LEFT JOIN. Also be sure that the query select * from FROM OPENQUERY(SRV_BASEDEDATOSX, 'SELECT rcod, name FROM recetas') AS R returns the desired records

Comment: Thanks for helping me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depending on the result set's size you are fetching it happens sometimes when you use open query. try this it might help:

```
SELECT P.idp, P.cod, R.name, P.idtp, T_P.tp, I.i, P_I.txt
FROM [SRV_BASEDEDATOSX]..[your on schema name oracle ].[recetas] AS R
RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.DISH AS P ON P.cod = R.rcod
INNER JOIN dbo.DISH_I AS P_I ON P_I.idp = P.idp
INNER JOIN dbo.TYPE_P AS T_P ON T_P.idtp = T_P.idtp
INNER JOIN dbo.LENGUAJE AS I ON I.idI = P_I.idi
```

Comment: forgive me for my lack of knowledge,

`[SRV_BASEDEDATOSX]..[your on schema name oracle ].[recetas]` can you tell me what you mean? and how can I know what it is? Because the database that I connect is from a third party.

Comment: nobody has complete knowledge dont worry. follow this path on sql server : object explorer --> server  object --> linked servers --> [SRV_BASEDEDATOSX]--> catalogs --> defaults --> tables-->[recetas]-->right click--> script table as --> select to

Comment: Thank you very much, it has been very helpful and I have managed to solve the problem.
Now I'm going to investigate a little more about this.
Thank you very much

Comment: i'm happy that it helped